# How to keep libev running even if all watchers are stopped

Tags: c, linux, libev

How to keep `libev` running even if all watchers are stopped?

Comment: My solution is to add a timer event that will never be stopped.But it maybe a little ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ev_ref()` function to increase a reference counter in the event loop. It will cause the event loop to run forever or till you explicitly call `ev_unref()` function.

http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/libev/ev.pod#FUNCTIONS_CONTROLLING_EVENT_LOOPS